# CMake does not find correct library and include path using FIND_PACKAGE(OpenSSL)

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

I have a compilied OpenSSL library for different architectures:

> contrib/openssl/include
>
> contrib/openssl/arm64
>
> contrib/openssl/arm32
>
> contrib/openssl/x86_64

In my CMake file there is something with 'FIND_PACKAGE(OpenSSL)'.

The problem is that CMake is not able to use provided header files from "/include" and search for correct library which match the architecture.

I have tried it with '-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=contrib/openssl/' but CMake does not find correct library and is using the system path.

Using '-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=contrib/openssl/contrib/arm64' does find the OpenSSL library but is using the header files from system path (which is wrong because my host system is using OpenSSL 1.0.x and my external OpenSSL version is 1.1.1d).

**Question**

How to fix?

**My nasty solution**

I provide some special "-DOWN_OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY" and "-DOWN_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR" defines to override the extracted paths:

```
  SET(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${OWN_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
  SET(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY ${OWN_OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY})
```

Try to build libarchive:
https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Note, that [FindOpenSSL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html) module, used by call to `find_package(OpenSSL)`, is expected the package to be installed by **regular means**. If you moved or renamed files/directories after installation, the module may do not work.

Comment: Did you clean your CMakeCache before changing OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR? If not you should delete your cache and re-configure with the -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR option

Comment: @Developer Paul: Of course...I have ran a "git clean -fdx".

Comment: Sometimes someone has to ask the stupid questions ;) Based on the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) it looks like you can pass `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` to the find package call which may skip the system location for OpenSSL.